# Perl namespace problem: using exported functions in modules not working

Tags: perl

I'm packaging some common functions in a small Perl module, that I load in the script using

```
use lib path/to/lib
```

In the module file I imported some other system installed modules (e.g. `Carp qw(confess)`, but I cannot invoke `confess` directly, but rather `Carp::confess`, which is unusual to me.

This is my (non)-working example:
https://github.com/telatin/bioinfo/blob/master/mini/script.pl

```
use 5.012;
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "$Bin/Demo/lib";
use Local::Module;

say "Version: ", $Local::Module::VERSION;

Local::Module->new();
```

The module: https://github.com/telatin/bioinfo/blob/master/mini/Demo/lib/Local/Module.pm

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;
use Carp qw(confess);
package Local::Module;
$Local::Module::VERSION = 2;


sub new {
    my ($class, $args) = @_;
    my $self = {
        debug   => $args->{debug}, 
    };
    my $object = bless $self, $class;

    confess "Unable to create fake object";
    return $object;
}

1;
```

What should I do in the *.pm* file to avoid this problem?

Comment: Tip: `$Bin` should be `$RealBin`. That way, the program will keep working if you create a symlink to the program

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;
use Carp qw(confess);
package Local::Module;
```

First you load `Carp` and import `confess`, but at that point you're still in package `main`, so `confess` is imported into `main`.

Then you switch packages with `package Local::Module`, but there is no `confess` function defined here.

You need to switch packages first:

```
package Local::Module;
use 5.012;
use warnings;
use Carp qw(confess);
```

Now all imports and all the following code are in the same package.